# using the mail command

Tags: command-line, email

How do I use the mail command to check email (and send email) from gmail. Does it support labels? I couldn't have figure out where to put the username and password. 
I tried to search for instruction but couldn't find any

Answer (score 10):

The `mail` command is an old and primitive mail client. It only supports reading mail locally on a unix server, typically stored in [mbox format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) in `/var/mail` or a similar location.

To read [Gmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail) mail, you need to either use their web interface, or use a client that works with Gmail's [POP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POP3) or [IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP) access, or use the unmaintained [Gmailfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmailfs) (not recommended for inexperienced users). I recommend IMAP (make sure that you've enabled IMAP access in your account).

There are many email clients that support IMAP. On the command line, you could use [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org/), [Sup](http://supmua.org/), one of the [Emacs mail clients](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryMail), or many others. Just about any GUI mail client supports IMAP. IMAP only defined folders, not labels (the difference is that a mail is only in one folder but can have many labels); not all good IMAP clients are good at managing labels, and I don't know what clients support labels well.

Another approach would be to have Gmail forward all mails to your machine. But that requires an always-on, always-connected machine, and some technical know-how. I don't recommend this for an inexperienced user. And I'd recommend a more modern mail client than `mail` anyway.

Comment: I tried to configure gnus (emacs client) to access gmail but I couldn't have figure which file to use. I followed this [link](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnusGmail)

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use fetchmail to pull the mail from Gmail and put it in the local mbox file.