# Command line e-mailing

Tags: email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use the “mail” command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26790/how-can-i-use-the-mail-command)

I have `mutt` configured for CLI e-mailing. All's golden with the "this one just sucks less" client but...

I am now on a machine on which I can't install `mutt` at all, not even on my `$HOME`, so:

- is there a way to use `mail` (`/usr/bin/mail`) to the same effect?

I Googled to no avail. Maybe it's because the term "mail" is not easy to "disambiguate" in a search?

Comment: If google's not being helpful, search on the right corner directly here

Answer (score 3):

Linux and Unix systems generally have `/usr/bin/mail` on the host. You can use mail (just run `mail` on the command line) to read/send mail.

If you need to mail files, you can:

```
cat file.txt | mail -s "subject" user@domain
```

If you need to mail large files, you can `uuencode` them as attachments:

```
uuencode file file | mail -s "here is your file" user@domain
```